# How can I loop through this array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array of objects here:

```
const users = [
    {
        name: 'xyz',
        claims: [
            {"location": 'dallas',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'frisco',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'plano',
            "id": '123'},
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'abc',
        claims: [
            {"location": 'richardson',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'rowlett',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'dallas',
            "id": '123'},
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'adr',
        claims: [
            {"location": 'frisco',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'irving',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'dallas',
            "id": '123'},
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get all the locations with dallas as the value. How can I do that? I know I would probably use a loop (maybe a forEach) but I am not exactly sure how  I could get the values that I need. Would I use filter?

Comment: `I want to get all the locations with dallas as the value` <- What do you want to get exactly? The `id`?

Comment: You would use .filter(). When I get to a computer I'll get something mocked up for you.

Comment: `users.map(u => u.claims).flat().filter(c => c. location === 'dallas')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten the mapped array after filtering the locations which equal to **dallas**.

```js
const users = [
    {
        name: 'xyz',
        claims: [
            {"location": 'dallas',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'frisco',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'plano',
            "id": '123'},
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'abc',
        claims: [
            {"location": 'richardson',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'rowlett',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'dallas',
            "id": '123'},
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'adr',
        claims: [
            {"location": 'frisco',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'irving',
            "id": '123'},
            {"location": 'dallas',
            "id": '123'},
        ]
    }
]

const result = users.flatMap(u => u.claims.filter(c => c.location === 'dallas'))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I failed a interview for not knowing this lol I was trying to filter and that’s it. I see where I went wrong and I will never forget the use case for flatMap again!

Comment: You are welcome, Never mind about the interview, and try to train on arrays high order methods, like `flat`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `reduce`, `reduceRight`, `map`, `forEach`, `some`, `every` and try to know the uses of each of them, and I wish you good luck in the next interview.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap` with combination of `filter`:

```js
const dallasLocations = users.flatMap(user => {
    return user.claims.filter(claim => claim.location === 'dallas')
})
```